# Where to put a JS file for specific page in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm using an autocomplete JQuery plugin with some options. The little code is used in just one specific page.

My first attempt was to put it in a separated JS file in `app/assets/javascripts/foo.js`. The problem is that the code throws an exception because the element does not exist in other pages.

I also thought about calling the JS file from the specific page but where should I put this JS file?

**EDIT 1**

This is the code of foo.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").autocomplete({
         // set options
    }) 
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = 
        function( ul, item ) {
        // more code
        };
});
```

I get the `typeerror $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is null` in firebug so I tried put this code into the specific page with `<script></script>` and works fine but I don't like this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this. Possibly the easiest would be to take all the relevant js and put it directly in the page it's concerned with - just add a script tag, put it inside, and be done with it.

I'm not a huge fan of this approach, and it wouldn't work in every circumstance. I'm going to go ahead and guess that in `assets/javascripts`, you have a "require_tree ." that combines & serves every file in the folder. What you could do is break this down a bit - keep every file that you server on every page in a specific, separate folder, and require every file within that folder. Keep things like `foo.js` elsewhere, and combine/serve them on an as-need basis.

I can't say for sure, but I'm guessing this division of JavaScript files will be overkill. I think the best thing to do though is change the structure of `foo.js` so you can still serve it with everything else, but it will not automatically run. There's a couple of ways to do this. One would be to just wrap everything in a named function, and call the function on the specific page that needs it would work.

---

However, if the issue is just a matter of configuring a jQuery plug-in, you may be able to rely on jQuery more to do this. I'd have to see the code in question, but you *should* be able to call a plug-in on an empty set.

For instance, if you're using jQuery-ui and declare something as draggable, `$("#my_element").draggable()` won't cause an exception if "#my_element" doesn't exist on the page - rather, nothing at all will happen. I can't say for sure without seeing what you're doing, but I'd bet you can get away with a clever restructure of `foo.js` and have it exist harmlessly on pages that don't need it.

---

With regards to **Edit 1**:

An easy, if somewhat gimmicky, fix would just be do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").autocomplete({
     // set options
  })
  .each(function() {
    $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = 
      function( ul, item ) {
      // more code
      };
  });
```

I don't know quite enough about the jQuery UI widgets to know if there's a better way - ideally, there'd be some way to include the `_renderItem` function as part of the configuration for autocomplete. I'm going to do a bit more digging, but otherwise this is a reasonable way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, I'm using JQuery-ui with autocomplete like `$("#search").autocomplete(...)` and throw the exception in firebug: `typeerror $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is null`

Comment: Hmm. Is there any chance you can post a bit more code? I think that even if there is no element, the block you posted should return "null" without causing any errors - are you subsequently trying to use what this block returns or something?

Comment: Updated with a method that should allow you to keep everything in the same spot a before.

Comment: Thanks, now the exceptions disappeared! But for some reason, autocomplete does not work the first time that the page is loaded but if I refresh works fine :(.

Comment: Odd. If you clear your cache, does it still do this? Also, does the "#search" element start in the html on the page, or does it get added by a separate script?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to put this file outside of the asset pipeline, meaning not inside `app/assets`, `lib/assets`, or `public/assets`.  You could put it in the `public` folder, and then link to it using `javascript_include_tag` in the view you need it in.